# How to read all email addresses, phone numbers etc stored in a windows phone contact?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

We can get 'ONE' phone number, email address etc of a contact with this code.

```
Contacts ContactsObj = new Contacts();
ContactsObj.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(func);
ContactsObj.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
```

/

```
void func(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var result in e.Results)
        {
            txtBlock.Text += result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault()+ "," + result.EmailAddresses.FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
```

But as there can be more emails/numbers stored in one contact. Is there a way to get all phone numbers, email addresses etc of a contact in a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access more than 1 email Ids and Phone Numbers by using foreach.
The following code worked for me.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Phone.UserData.ContactEmailAddress ad in result.EmailAddresses)
{
    txtBlock.Text += ad.EmailAddress;
}
foreach (Microsoft.Phone.UserData.ContactPhoneNumber ph in result.PhoneNumbers)
{
txtBlock.Text += ph.PhoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: If the contact person and his related email address is not important, this is simple and good code, but one user may have many Email address.
By the above code you will not be able to identify which contact person owns the email address,

Comment: Thanks! this works great but contact's addresses can't be retrieved by this method.